# Auto stretch div when it's default height/width is filled

Tags: html, css, stretching

my template is as follows:

[image]

```
.layout{

height:100%;
width: 70%;
position: fixed;

}

.header{

height:20%;
width: 100%;

}

.content{

height:60%;
width: 100%;

}

.footer{

height:20%;
width: 100%;

}
```

the **content** has a **default height 60%**, and i want if the **content** is **filled** with data to get **auto stretch** for (height/width) when necessary, and a scroll appears for whole page, how to do so ?

i tried the solution for giving the **parent** `postion:relative;` but that will ignore the default height and minimize the content in case of the content has small data, and i want to keep default height in case of small data.

Comment: Have you tried the min-height declaration?

Comment: Do you want 1/ a vertical scroll if needed and if not the footer should be already at the bottom of the viewport with the content spanning from the header down to the footer or 2/ an horizontal scroll if needed but no vertical scroll ?

Comment: i need both vertical and or horizontal when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by Motoxer4533, use the min-height property: http://jsfiddle.net/uef7v/

Comment: min-height will fix the default height, but for stretching i will need relative, right ? no other solution for stretching ?

Comment: what exactly do you meen by 'stretching'? what is missing in my jsfiddle?

Comment: managed to do it by giving `min-height` to content, and `overflow: scroll;` to the parent

Comment: how to add horizontal scroll too to the content div ?

Comment: yes, sure but i think i will better post that in a separate question :)

Answer (score 1):

just set the `.content` height with `min-height` property:

```
.content{
   min-height:60%;
}
```

that will set the minimum height of `.content` to 60% and if the data of the content take up more that 60% it will **stretch automatically**.
but you need to drop the position:fixed on layout. you don't need that if your content is dynamic.

Comment: how to add horizontal scroll too ?