# Make div same size of its contents

Tags: html

I would like to know if there's a way so you can make a div have the width and the height of its contents, no mater what?

So far I have tried with several css rules but nothing seems to be working.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your html/css so far?

Comment: I think your question is answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463787/auto-stretch-div-when-its-default-height-width-is-filled

Comment: Another matching question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981290/can-not-stretch-the-css-divs-100-vertically-and-horizontally

Answer (score 1):

Make your divider float, it will sets to **mininum** size.

```
<div style="float:left">this way</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that:

1. Use float with min-width/height.
2. Use Inline-Block.
3. Use Absolut positioning.
4. Use javascript
5. Wait for future new properties of width such as 'fit-content'. **CSS4**